Using past perfect with different verbs

When I got home she had cleaned the house- meaning is simple. She did clean the house before I got there

When I read a book she had cleaned the house- in my first example "get home" is a short action. I wonder if past perfect works in my other sentence with "read a book" to show that house was already cleaned before reading a book?



It's syntactically valid, but I can't think of any context where a native Anglophone would say or write When I read a book she had cleaned the house. You don't really need to jump through hoops and include Simple Past and Past Perfect anyway - just say After she [had] cleaned the house I read a book. Where [had] is valid, but I wouldn't include it anyway - it serves no purpose, being both syntactically and semantically superfluous. And I suggest you make life easier for yourself with #1 - just change ambiguous when to before, then you don't need any complex verb forms.

@FumbleFingers "When I was reading a book she had cleaned the house" on the other hand would be plain wrong, right?

It is not the duration of the action that matters but whether the verb admits a sense of completion. Getting home does, reading a book doesn't.

@TimR  so  2 is wrong?

#2 has no clear meaning. It's clear that she had cleaned the house but it isn't clear what is meant by "when I read a book".  When I finished the book I was reading?

@TimR clear sense of completiton,yes? What about "when he repaired my car I had already paid" I think that one works clear sense of completion and money given before the end of working?

You consistently confuse the issue of what verb forms are suitable for two temporally-related clauses by linking them with ambiguous / non-idiomatic subordinate conjunctions such as when and once. FYI, When I read a book she had cleaned the house is syntactically valid, but semantic nonsense without insane levels of contrivance. On the other hand, non-ambiguous  While I read a book she had cleaned the house is simply syntactically invalid, so no-one expects it to mean anything.

@TimR but we wouldn't say "When I finished my book, she had cleaned the house."

To use she had cleaned the house,
the comparison event needs to be a definite start or end point,
like that in example 1:

When I got home, she had cleaned the house.

When I got home is a definite point in time, and hence the sentence is valid.
In example 2,

*When I read a book, she had cleaned the house.

When I read a book doesn't refer to a definite point in time.
To say the house was already cleaned before the commencement of the reading, we could say
By the time I started to read a book, she had cleaned the house.
